# Electron JS write file permission problems

Tags: node.js, electron

We are developing an Electron JS app which should get a configuration file from a server at one part. This worked until an hour ago, but now it "magically" throws a permission error. It throws a permission error when we try to write to anything. Here is what we explicitly tested:

- app.getPath('userData')
- "C:/test"
- app.getAppPath()

We tried lauching it from an administrator elevated powershell, but still no success. This is our code snippet:

```
function canWrite(path, callback) {
    fs.access(path, fs.W_OK, function (err) {
        callback(null, !err);
    });
}

function downloadFile(url, target, target_name) {
    canWrite(target, function (err, isWritable) {
        if (isWritable){
            electronDl.download(
                BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(),
                url,
                {
                    directory: target,
                    filename: target_name
                }
            )
            console.log("Downloaded from: " + url + " to: " + target);
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("No permission to write to target");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
downloadFile(REMOTEURL, app.getPath('userData'), 'sessionfile.json');
```

We rewrote this code, tried to change filenames, tried it without the filename (..) and are a bit out of ideas now. We furthermore implemented a file check (whether the file exists or not) and if so a deletion before executing this. We commented it out for now for debugging because it worked before.

**Update:**
After somebody pointed out that the outer check is pretty useless, I updated the code to this (still doesn't work):

```
function downloadFile(url, target) {
    electronDl.download(
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(),
        url,
        {
            directory: target,
        }
    )
}
downloadFile(REMOTEURL, "C:/test");
```

Comment: AFAIK the file needs to exist to be writable. Furthermore, can you do `console.log(err)` inside `fs.access`? This should print a meaningful error message, either on the terminal or within the DevTool console (depending on this code is run).

Comment: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'C:\test'` is the error code you asked for. And shouldn't the downloader be able to create a file? I mean most files you download are new to your computer after all, right?

Comment: Judging from the error message, the directory doesn't exist. `electron-dl` will create directories as needed, but your outer check prohibits the download if the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @snwflk I created the directory and it worked. But when I excluded the outer check, it doesn't work anymore. I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears that `electron-dl` doesn't give clear error messages, you may want to check/create the directory beforehand as you initially did.

The basic procedure could look like this:

- Check if the target directory exists.

  - If it exists, check if it is writable.

    - If it is writable, proceed to downloading.
    - If it is not writable, print an informative error message and stop.
  - If it doesn't exist, try to create it.

    - If this works, proceed to downloading.
    - If this fails, print an informative error message and stop.

The following code implements this idea (using the synchronous versions of the `fs` methods for simplicity). Be sure to use the asynchronous versions if required.

```js
const electronDl = require('electron-dl')
const fs = require('fs')

function ensureDirExistsAndWritable(dir) {
    if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        try {
            fs.accessSync(dir, fs.constants.W_OK)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Cannot access directory')
            return false
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir)
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e.code == 'EACCES') {
                console.log('Cannot create directory')
            }
            else {
                console.log(e.code)
            }
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}


function downloadFile(url, target) {
    if (ensureDirExistsAndWritable(target) == false) {
        return
    }

    electronDl.download(
        BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(),
        url,
        {
            directory: target,
        }
    )
    .then(
        dl => console.log('Successfully downloaded to ' + dl.getSavePath())
    )
    .catch(
        console.log('There was an error downloading the file')
    )
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much and implemented it like this, but it drops out at the error catch in the downloadFile function at .catch.

Comment: I am getting an error message similar to [this now](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl/issues/42) and I guess this was the problem from the beginning so I will look into that now. Seems like bug to me, but I will mark this answer as accepted, as it would solve any kind of permission error, and that is what the question was about in the first place.

Comment: You mean `Cannot read property 'webContents' of null`? Just to be sure, is (one of) your BrowserWindow(s) focused? During my testing I got the same message when this wasn't the case. If possible, I'd pass in a window variable.

Comment: You are so right! As I tried to get the file as fast as possible, I totally ignored that there was no focused browser window created! This was the whole problem. Thank you so much!